# How to loop through mixed numbers in Bash

Tags: bash

For example:

```
for s in 1..5,20..23,97..99;
do
   echo $s;
done
1..5,
20..23,
97..99
```

How to make it loop through 1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22,23,97,98,99?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) `{ }` syntax:

```
for num in {1..5} {20..23} {97..99}; do
   echo "$num"
done
```

Comment: might be better in full form `{{1..5},{20..23},{97..99}}` preventing accidents when space is missing `{1..5} {20..23}{97..99}` which will give you `1 2 3 4 5 2097 2098 2099 2197 2198 2199 2297 2298 2299 2397 2398 2399`

Comment: @karakfa Well, either you have to remember to use a space or to use a comma. `{{1..5},{20..23}{97..99}}` would do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seq`,

```
 for s in $(seq 1 5) $(seq 20 23) $(seq 97 99);
 do
   echo $s;
 done
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
20
21
22
23
97
98
99
```

brace expansion `{ }` is another choice.